# JAVA ClassLoad same class name

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Yesterday i thought one question ,below is the detail:

I have 3 JAR files, **a.jar**, **b.jar** ,**c.jar** . both these jars files have a class named **com.test.Test** ,and **sayHello()** was defined in this class.

I create  a  web application,  i reference a.jar,b.jar,c.jar . And in main method, i involve sayHello(); .at this time, which com.test.Test  will be load?

the result is a.jar.

any body tell me the reason ?? thanks in advance!!!

Comment: you can easily test it yourself by making sayHello method print something slightly different from one to the others.

Comment: yes, i did this. a.jar was loaded. i want to know why :)

Comment: oh sorry. i missed the part that you answered your own question.

Answer (score 3):

That is what java [language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html) says. It loads what ever the class first occurs in **classpath** and ignores other.

Comment: why b.jar is not the 1st occurs in classpath.

Comment: classpath is set by you. You can modify classpath and bring b.jar as first and a.jar as second. Why b.jar is in second place? You need to tell us. JVM don't restrict you from moving, unless b.jar has some dependency on a.jar.

Comment: ok, but if in an web application ? i put these jar under/web-inf/lib/. i didnt modify the classpath .

Comment: If they are in WEB_INF/lib, you can't control. As Edwin suggested, you need to rethink about your packaging structure.

Comment: yes, that's true. But when we are doing project, we must refer 3rd part jars. Especially jar file upgrade, some guys put old version and latest version under lib...:(

Comment: Yes, I think this might be time to remove older versions and upgrade related code also. I can understand the pain and pressure, but unfortunately no other option.

Comment: The thing with multiple jars in the classpath is a great example of the jar-hell :-) You might be interested with JBoss Modules or OSGi which allows you to put jars/classes into different bundles / modules that are visible for specified clients.

Comment: Within the WEB-INF/lib you can't control which ones are loaded first. That will depend on the application server you use.
But most will probably use a name-based order, so a, b, c, ...

You can also write you own ClassLoader to have more control.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of focusing on which one will be loaded, realize that the stuff within the JAR files probably need *their* `com.test.Test` class instead of *someone else's* `com.test.Test` to work properly.  That means *for a functional system* you'll have to make a way that `a.jar` finds `a.jar's` `com.test.Test` instead of the one in `b.jar`.  The same goes for `b.jar` finding it's classes *in preference to* `a.jar's`.

The only way to do this is to use a framework which *adds* name spacing *beyond* the java package mechanism.  This is typically done with multiple classloaders, often one for each JAR file.  You can write such a thing yourself ([Tomcat did](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)), where you need to specify the rules for cross-loader discovery, or use something akin to a [OSGi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) framework.

Comment: i just want to know the mechanism of ClassReload in a web app.

Comment: There is no true "reload".  The web application dereferences the "holding" class loader and creates a new one, and then sends the new one through the initialization routines, reading the web.xml and loading classes according to configuration.  The old one (when deferenced) becomes unreachable by the main thread of execution of the JVM, and gets garbage collected (which will also garbage collect all of the previous knowledge of the previous class definitions).

Comment: i am thinking if Loader are compare ASCII code of each jar file name, eg:a==>65, b==>66 ,so a.jar was loaded. i also tried other names.

Comment: @user1698495 That's just not how it is done.  It's well documented how it works, and you can read the documentation here.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html  If it doesn't work that way, it's not Java.

Comment: okay, let me check this doc first. thanks Buddy ... i was focus on this point whole night, will go to office later :((

Comment: @user1698495 If you have the time, try to read specifications.  They often save you from _thinking_ something works one way by _telling_ you the only permitted ways something may work.  Without occasionally checking the specification references, you run the risk of having your mental image of the system drift from the actual way the system works.  RFCs, OSGI Alliance, ISO papers, and such are your dear, __dear__ friends.

Answer (score 0):

Whichever Jar File comes first in your classpath will be used..
You can modify your `CLASSPATH` environment variable to the path of your Jar file

Suppose you modify it as below: -

`set CLASSPATH = %CLASSPATH%;.;a.jar;b.jar`

then a.jar will be used..

You can also modify it by: -

`set CLASSPATH = %CLASSPATH%;.;b.jar;a.jar`

In this case, b.jar will be used..
These commands you need to run from your `Command Line`..

** NOTE: - If you are using any IDE, then they don't use System Classpath.. You need to set different classpath for the IDE you are using..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IDE, such as eclipse, you can modify your classpath on the properties of the project, then go to Build Path, and then you have the Order and Export tab where you can move up and down the jars. The one of the top will be the first taken by your application.

This you can also do manually by editing the file called "classpath" which is on your project and move to the top the jar you want your application to use first.

Comment: yes. for java project, this can be done. How abt in a web application la? as u no ,we just put jar files under /lib/...